# Connect to Redshift Database from Laravel 5 using Pgsql Driver?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, amazon-redshift

I was wondering if anyone knew whether the above was likely to be achievable or if I'm doing something nonsensical. These connection details work to an RDS (i.e. blah.blah.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com) database:

```
'db1' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST_BRAIN'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_BRAIN'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_BRAIN'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_BRAIN'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'xyz_admin',
    ],
```

but these do not work to a Redshift (i.e. blah.blah.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com) database:

```
'db2' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST_PINKY'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_PINKY'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_PINKY'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_PINKY'),
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT_PINKY'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'xyz',
    ],
```

Assuming all the details are correct, is there a compelling reason why this is never going to work? Is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: Why? Redshift isn't really an OLTP database intended for the kind of queries an ORM generates. I don't understand why you'd want to do this.

Comment: Response just in from the Redshift department: "The kind of queries that the ORM generates are in the kind of language that the database understands (SQL) and we only need the barest of cooperation from the ORM in order to generate simple SQL queries. We want to do this because the data wants to be free and because it’s there." I don't know, is this really unreasonable?

Comment: @thesunneversets did you find a solution??

Answer (score 1):

As long as the environment variables are correct, your config works for connecting to Redshift:

```
$take_over_the_world = DB::connection('db2')->select('SELECT tonight FROM going_to_do');
```